# Bootstrap Form Email, Range and Button are "disabled", but why?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Why i can't change the range, type an e-mailadress or click the button?
And my javascript dont get the event too... i am so stupid. i learn this never in my life.

I created this form with many kinds of input. Number, Dropdown and Checkbox works fine.
I don't get it. Maybe you see a mistake and could help me with this.

Happy Holidays. Stay safe.

```js
"use strict"

let formular = document.querySelector("form");

formular.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
});
```

```css
body {
    background: rgb(14,108,255);
    background: linear-gradient(49deg, rgba(14,108,255,0.5326505602240896) 0%, rgba(0,84,171,0.4654236694677871) 24%, rgba(14,173,255,0.4430147058823529) 66%, rgba(14,92,255,0.4206057422969187) 100%);
}

.fontBGtrans {
    background-color: #ffffff8a; 
    
}

.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Made it responsive -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Some TExt</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS loading -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Loading my css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- ### NAVIGATION AREA -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Some TExt</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Some TExt</a>
      </li>  
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Some TExt <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>      
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Some TExt
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="oldtimer-und-youngtimer.html">Some TExt </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some TExt</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some TExt</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some TExt</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some TExt</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some TExt</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some TExt</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some TExt</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some TExt</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some TExt</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some TExt</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Impressum</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
      <div class="container" style="margin-top: 4rem;">
        <div class="card bg-light mb-3 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="Some TExt">
          <div class="card-img-overlay">
      </div>
          <div class="card-body calculator">
            <h1 class="card-title"> Some TExt</h1>
            <p class="card-text text-justify">Some TExt </p>
            <form id="calculator-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Some TExt</label>
                      </div>
                      <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                        <option selected>PKW Motor</option>
                        <option value="1">Some TExt</option>
                        <option value="2">Some TExt</option>
                        <option value="3">Some TExt</option>
                        <option value="4">Some TExt.</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Some TExt</span>
                      </div>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="area" placeholder="Some TExt">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><br>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Some TExt</label>
                      </div>      
                      <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                        <option selected>Some TExt</option>
                        <option value="1">Some TExt</option>
                        <option value="2">Some TExt</option>
                        <option value="3">Some TExt</option>
                        <option value="4">Sonstiges</option>
                      </select>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
<!-- ### RANGE -->
                      <label for="formControlRange">WHY DOESNT WORK???</label>
                      <input type="range" class="form-control-range" id="formControlRange">
                    </div>
                      <br>
                       <p style="text-align: center;">Some TExt</p>
                          <!-- ### ZIP CODE -->
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">ZIP CODE</span>
                      </div>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="area" placeholder="Für ein Angebot aus Ihrer Region">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
<!-- ### EMAIL -->
                      <label for="customermail"></label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="customermail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="MAILADRESS - WHY DOESNT WORK???">
                      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">WHY DOESNT WORK???</small>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3 form-check">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Some TExt</label>
                    </div>
<!-- ### BTTN -->
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">WHY DOESNT WORK</button>
                    <br><br>
                    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Kosten jetzt online berechnen</button><br> -->
              </div>
            </form>
              <p class="card-text text-center"><small class="text-muted">Some TExt</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript loading -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="calculator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inspect, there is some overlay div which is not allowing you to click/fill form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div class="card-img-overlay"></div>` is above your form elements.
You can solve it by adding `pointer-events: none` to `.card-img-overlay` to make it transparent.
It should also work with z-index.

Comment: Yeah, this works now. Can you explain me why? I want to use this div, to write a Text as a overlay to the image `class="card-img-top"` but I decided against it.